# Separate ObservableCollections from each other

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

### Info

I have two `ObservableCollection` of the same `Screenshot`object. One is called `Screenshots` which contains all the possible screens available to the user and one is called `SelectedScreenshots` which is the selected screens the user wants to combine. I am adding a new screen into `SelectedScreenshots` every time the user selects a screen by click on a list which is binded in WPF to `Screenshots`

### Problem

The problem is that when I refresh the screens and clear `Screenshots` so that I see what has been updated on the screen it also clears `SelectedScreenshots` even though it is a different object. I do understand that they are pointing to the same location in memory, but how do I go around that? Deep copying is one solution. Is there any alternative?

### Code

The properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<Screenshot> Screenshots { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Screenshot>();

public ObservableCollection<Screenshot> SelectedScreenshots { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Screenshot>();
```

Initializing and refreshing the screens here:

```
private void InitScreens()
{
    var screenshots = Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(scrn => scrn.Bounds.Location.X).ThenBy(scrn => scrn.Bounds.Location.Y).Select(screen => new Screenshot(GetScreenImage(screen.Bounds), screen.DeviceName));

    App.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(delegate
    {    
        Screenshots.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Screenshots.Add(screenshots.ElementAt(i));
        }
    });
}
```

Adding and removing from the `SelectedScreenshots`:

```
private void lst_ScreenShots_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Screenshot item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        vm.SelectedScreenshots.Remove(item);
    }

    foreach (Screenshot item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        vm.SelectedScreenshots.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The Screenshot class:

```
public class Screenshot : ViewModelBase
{
    private BitmapImage _screenImage;
    public BitmapImage ScreenImage
    {
        get { return _screenImage; }
        set
        {
            _screenImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Screenshot(BitmapImage screenImage, string name)
    {
        this.ScreenImage = screenImage;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the observable collections are in fact **not** pointing to the same location in memory, as you initialized them to separate new objects. The items in the lists point to the same location in memory, but removing an item from a collection doesn't remove it from memory (at least not right away) so the other list still maintains the screenshot object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Screenshot object has properties that are reference types, then I think you will need to do as you said; perform a deep copy to ensure that the Screenshot object in your Screenshots property and the Screenshot object in your SelectedScreenshots property are not pointing to the same memory location.  In the past, I've created a PerformDeepCopy() method in the object, which in your case is the Screenshot object.  In this method, you can perform a MemberwiseClone(), which is a shallow copy.  This will copy the Name property in your Screenshot class.  Then you will manually assign a new memory address to the reference types.  This is where the BitmapImage property is "newed up".  The return value is a new Screenshot object.  For example:

```
public class Screenshot : ViewModelBase
{
    private BitmapImage _screenImage;
    public BitmapImage ScreenImage
    {
        get { return _screenImage; }
        set
        {
            _screenImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Screenshot(BitmapImage screenImage, string name)
    {
        this.ScreenImage = screenImage;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public Screenshot PerformDeepCopy()
    {
        Screenshot deepCopy = (Screenshot)this.MemberwiseClone();
        deepCopy.ScreenImage = new BitmapImage(this.ScreenImage.UriSource);
        return deepCopy;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the Screenshot class so that you can edit your answer to match it. It will help whomever is viewing it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It is the UI that is clearing SelectedScreenshots, since the control that you are binding to can only have selected items that exist in the items source and on each refresh you are creating an entirely new set of screenshots.

The solution would either be to save the selected items to another collection before the refresh and re-select after or to just update the existing set of screenshots.

I expect you will want to retain the selected screenshots in the UI. In order to achieve this you will need to somehow link the old screenshot instances to the new ones. Hopefully you can do this with the DeviceName? Or by the order? Will leave that bit up to you.

```
private void InitScreens()
{
    var screenshots = Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(scrn => scrn.Bounds.Location.X).ThenBy(scrn => scrn.Bounds.Location.Y).Select(screen => new Screenshot(GetScreenImage(screen.Bounds), screen.DeviceName));

    App.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(delegate
    {
        // store current selections
        var currentSelections = SelectedScreenshots.ToArray();

        Screenshots.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Screenshots.Add(screenshots.ElementAt(i));
        }

        // select what was previously selected
        SelectedScreenshots = new ObservableCollection<Screenshot>(Screenshots
           .Where(s => currentSelections.Any(c => c.DeviceName == s.DeviceName)));
    });
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue. It will get the latest screen rather than the previously selected screen because you are doing a .Where on the newly resetted Screenshots ObservableCollection.

Comment: The Where part of the code is picking the selected screenshots from the new set of instances by trying to find matching screenshots in the old instances. I don't know whether device name is the correct property to use, maybe it should be done on index. Its not clear what you are try to achieve.

Comment: Ah I think I might get it. Although you are clearing the collection of screenshots on refresh, you still want instances from the old collection to remain??

Comment: Correct! I want the user to be able to say "Here is a transition of what happened on my screen. Before and after."

Comment: Then I think all you need to do is remove Screenshots.Clear()? Its difficult to imagine exactly what your app needs to be doing.

Comment: Then I wouldn't be getting what is happening currently on the screen lol. I am refreshing it when I am clearing it.